# Join every other column with sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk, columns

I have a large text file (666000 colums) in the format

```
A B C D E F
```

Desired output

```
AB CD EF
```

How can we do it in `sed` or `awk`. I have tried a couple of things but nothing seems to be working. Please suggest something.

Comment: do you mean 666000 columns or 666000 rows?

Answer (score 3):

In `sed`:

```
sed 's! \([^ ]\+\)\( \|$\)!\1 !g' your_file
```

This will make the substitutions and print the result to standard out. To modify the file in place, add the `-i` switch:

```
sed -i 's! \([^ ]\+\)\( \|$\)!\1 !g' your_file
```

**Explanation**

This `sed` command will look for a space, followed by at least one non-space character, followed by a space or the end of the line. It substitutes this sequence with whatever non-space characters it found followed by a single space. The substitution is applied as many times as possible across the line (this is called a global substitution) because the `g` modifier is supplied at the end.
So, basically, with a sequence like `A B C`, `sed` will find the pattern " B " and substitute it with "B " leaving you with `AB C` as the final result.

**Assumptions made by this code**

This code assumes the spaces between your columns are really spaces and not TABs for example. This can be easily fixed at the expense of readability:

```
sed 's![[:blank:]]\+\([^[:blank:]]\+\)\([[:blank:]]\+\|$\)!\1 !g' your_file
```

Answer (score 2):

- awk:

  ```
  awk '{printf $1$2;for(i=3; i<=NF;i+=2){printf " %s",$i$(i+1)}print}' file
  ```

  This will probably be the fastest of the two for large files.
- Perl:

  ```
  perl -pe 's/([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/$1$2/g' file
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If your file indeed has that many columns, one option is to use gawk to treat each column as a record by setting `RS` to "one or more whitespace characters". This helps avoid having to set up a loop through the columns. Note that this solution is fragile in the face of an odd number of columns in a line.

```
awk --re-interval -v RS='[[:space:]]{1,}' '{x=$0; getline; printf x$0RT}' file
```